# What is the difference between github.com/jinzhu/gorm and gorm.io/gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using Go for application development, and I use the gorm library to connect to the database. I see gorm has 2 libraries `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` and `gorm.io/gorm`.

I don't know which one to use. How do they differ?

Answer (score 14):

Gorm version 1 up to v1.9.16 was kept at `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` and to import it from your code you would use that path:

```golang
import (
    ...
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)
```

Go convention is that when a new package version is no longer backwards compatible, the import path should change, so when putting out version 2 the team decided to move the repo to a new organisation on github: `https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm`, and this new version gets imported into your code using `gorm.io/gorm`:

```golang
import (
    ...
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)
```

(bear in mind that due to quirks in the go ecosystem, v2 is kept tagged as >= v1.20.0, confusing I know!)

Gorm v2 is generally quite close to v1 in syntax and function, but more powerful, consistent and has had a large number of bugs squashed out. I haven't seen benchmarks but from the box it should also be more performant due to using prepared statements.

All in all, there is no reason not to use v2 in a new project, and plenty of reasons to migrate away from v1 in existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's a same repo but jinzhu move GormV2 to new repo(https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm or gorm.io/gorm).
From my point of view, we should use update lib `github.com/go-gorm/gorm`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use `github.com/jinzhu/gorm`. Use `gorm.io/gorm`, because of my experience when using the old version sometimes an error appears

Comment: I see this is your first answer, if you could expand on what error you see and why not to use `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` that would improve your answer. As it stands this does not answer the question and is likely to be deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).